# Web Components - Shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Would HTML [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) not enable developers to target a subset of the DOM?  In terms of CSS's ability to target all `<div>`'s, doesn't the more specific selector (the one that says `[data-role="widget"]`) win?

Javascript has modular pattern design available.

Why do we need a shadow DOM?

Comment: The Shadow DOM is not a way to target a subset of the DOM.

Comment: Though I think this question is low quality, possibly duplicate and possibly offtopic I try to put it short: Web Components is more than custom tags. They encapsulate whole dom trees, logic with public interface and stylesheets in a registered component. It would look like the stylesheet defines and provide a defined interaction. Think of custom drop down or flyout menus, toggle buttons or even form components that should have a micro business logic. Web Components will encapsulate them, expose it as `<flyout>` and provide a `flyout.open();` the programmer internally implemented.

Comment: @try-catch-finally I don't think the Shadow DOM does all that.  Web Components do.  ...Web components seem to violate the KISS principle.